# Convert a 3d polygon to 3d polyline using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, 3d, geometry-conversion

I am using QGIS 2.16 to try to convert polygons with 3d vertices to polylines with 3d vertices.  Using the tool Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to Lines writes out the polyines, but the z information has been removed.  Am I missing something or is there another workaround in QGIS to achieve 3d polylines from 3d polygons?

Comment: FYI - I've just fixed this for QGIS 3.0 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/29d33b47fe050f1004cc8a5d8474018dd84ce72d

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to 2.18 you could use the "boundary" algorithm in the toolbox (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog218/index.html#feature-geometry-boundary-algorithm). This algorithm fully supports z/m values and curves, and given that the boundary of a polygon is the exterior and interior rings you'll get the same result as converting polygons to lines.